# Eclipse RCP Product Export

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When i try to Export my eclipse RCP product I have this problem :

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.  Software being installed: My Product 1.0.0.201503171025
>   (test.rcp.product_test 1.0.0.201503171025)  Missing requirement: My
>   Product 1.0.0.201503171025 (test.rcp.product_test 1.0.0.201503171025)
>   requires 'org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group
>   [1.1.0.v20120521-2329-8yFTIGIbGGduEZ6-7-jLx41nXj]' but it could not be
>   found

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must list all the features you require in your xxx.product file. This includes the Eclipse features you want to use. Specify this on the 'Dependencies' tab in the 'Features' list.

For a simple e4 application the required features would be

```
<your feature>
org.eclipse.e4.rcp
org.eclipse.emf.common
org.eclipse.emf.ecore
```

The target platform you use when doing the product export must contain these features.

Comment: Hello @greg-449 have you a tutorial : how to create and export an RCP application  because i have a problem : i can't launch my RCp application after exporting thanks :)

Comment: No I don't. The tutorials on http://www.vogella.com are usually good. But usually they are either about a 3.x style RCP or a pure e4 RCP